# How to get bucket count with condition in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to count all the unique sellers whose sell sum should be greater than 100.

I have tried this approach using **terms aggregation** but this will return a bucket list. But what I want is only the total seller count whose sell sum should be greater than 100.

Is there any way to do this using **cardinality** or anything else?

I have also tried with **cardinality** but not worked.

**Query**

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggregations": {
        "seller_count": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "seller_id"
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "total_sell": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "sell"
                    }
                },
                "sell_bucket_filter": {
                    "bucket_selector": {
                        "buckets_path": {
                            "totalSell": "total_sell"
                        },
                        "script": {
                            "source": "params.totalSell > 100"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use [stats bucket aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-stats-bucket-aggregation.html), to get the count of those `seller_id` whose `sell` sum is greater than 100**

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result.

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "sell": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "seller_id": 1,
  "sell": 50
}
{
  "seller_id": 2,
  "sell": 50
}
{
  "seller_id": 2,
  "sell": 60
}
{
  "seller_id": 3,
  "sell": 60
}
{
  "seller_id": 3,
  "sell": 100
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "seller_count": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "seller_id"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "total_sell": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "sell"
          }
        },
        "sell_bucket_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "totalSell": "total_sell"
            },
            "script": {
              "source": "params.totalSell > 100"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "bucketcount":{
      "stats_bucket":{
        "buckets_path":"seller_count._count"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "seller_count": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 2,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "total_sell": {
            "value": 110.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 3,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "total_sell": {
            "value": 160.0
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "bucketcount": {
      "count": 2,                 // note this
      "min": 2.0,
      "max": 2.0,
      "avg": 2.0,
      "sum": 4.0
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Rohit did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: Appreciate your quick response but there is one issue with this approach if bucket count is more than 10000 then i have to use composite aggregation. The problem with composite aggregation is that in the index one more field is present which is ‘product_id’ i want to count seller count for all the products in one query.

Comment: @Rohit thanks for your reply :) But you have not mentioned anything about composite aggregation or bucket count (greater than 10000) in the question. Since this is your different use case, and different from what you have asked, it would be great if you post a separate question for the same. As the question originally posted was to count the number of buckets only.